# IText Pdf Layout with Grid and Container

Tags: itext7

I have a layout where in there is a container then a grid and then a container again.I am trying to export this layout to pdf using Itext 7 but the grid starts from first page even though as per layout it is on second page.Can anybody help me with this?.The page dimension is 1366 X 768

The image depicts the exact thing I am trying to achieve:

[image: The image depicts the exact thing I am trying to achieve]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please show us your code and explain what you want to achieve in a clearer way. Have a look at `AreaBreak`, it might help you to move to the next page.

Comment: I have attached the screenshot for what I am trying to achieve.The screenshot contains much smaller grid than the actual grid.The grid could span across multiple pages.I want to have a layout exactly as depicted in the snapshot.I am stuck with this for days.I am newbie to itext  7 pdf.Using areabreak in my case will always cause the grid to start from new page.I want the grid to start below the container

Comment: Could you share the part of your code where you draw and/or insert the grid? It is hard to provide good advice if we don't know how you are doing it currently.